# PHP MYSQL BASIC QUESTION, IF QUERY EMPTY, HIDE IMAGE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I ask a php mysql basic question. I make a query and echo for images. in my code, if `'.$row['image'].'` is empty, it will show a small red cross image in the browser. how to hide the image if the query is empty?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE catalog='image'"); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<img src="'.$row['image'].'" />';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE catalog='image'"); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
if(!empty($row['image'])){
echo '<img src="'.$row['image'].'" />';
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all, all the answer is useful for me, I accept the right answer for the first answer post.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just check if `$row['image']` is empty?

```
if(!empty($row['image'])){
  echo '<img src="'.$row['image'].'" />';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE catalog='image'"); 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if(trim($row['image']) != '')
        echo '<img src="'.$row['image'].'" />';
    }
```